# Как записать строку в JSON-файл?

Tags: javascript, php, json, reactjs

Мне нужно записать строку в файл notes.json. Мой php-скрипт почему-то не работает. Ошибок нет, просто в файл строка не добавляется.

App:

```
import React, {
    Component
} from "react";
import Notes from "./Notes.js";
import $ from "jquery";
 
import {
    withoutIndex
} from "./utils.js"


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            notes: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getNotes();
    }

    
    async getNotes(){
        let notesList = [];
        await $.getJSON('./api/notes.json', function(data) {
            for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                notesList.push(data[i].text);
            }
           
        });
        await this.setState({
            notes: notesList
        });
    }

    async onNoteCreate(newNodeText){
        this.setState(oldState => {
             return {
                notes: [newNodeText].concat(oldState.notes)
            };
          });
        $.ajax({
            url: './api/saveNote.php',
            method: 'GET',
            async: false,
            data: {
                text: newNodeText
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <Notes
        notes={this.state.notes}
        onDelete={this.onNoteDelete.bind(this)}
        onCreate={this.onNoteCreate.bind(this)}
        />;
    }
}


export default App;
```

saveNote.php:

```
<?php

$text = $_POST["text"];
$notes = json_decode(file_get_contents("./api/notes.json"));

array_push($notes, ["text" => $text]);
file_put_contents("./api/notes.json", json_encode( $notes ));
```

Файл notes.json имеет такой вид:

```
[{"text":"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"}, 
{"text": "aezakmi"}]
```

Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку в файл notes.json добавлялся ключ "text" со значение из поля ввода.

Comment: Вы в `array_push` даете объект, а ему нужно массив. В `json_decode` вторым параметром укажите `true`, чтобы не объект получать, а массив.

Comment: А если 2 поста одновременно?
если text в json представляет ценность лучше делать по-другому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

автору возможно уже нашел ответ. не проверяя остальной код, для других с подобным вопросов хочу обратить внимание на совпадение работы с методами обмена. возможно указан не весь код. но из того что видно сохранение идет почему-то методом `get`, а чтение переменной для сохранения метода `post`. в таком случае не только нечего сохранять, но и должна быть ошибка инициализации переменной.

```
$.ajax({
            url: './api/saveNote.php',
            method: 'GET',
            async: false,
            data: {
                text: newNodeText
            }
        });


$text = $_POST["text"];
```